# Decrypt Firefox password database

Tags: c++, firefox, encryption

I want to write a simple utility that extracts passwords from a Firefox password database (the corresponding file is called `signons.sqlite` in the profile folder).

What I've done so far: Opened database using sqlite, retrieved encrypted username, encrypted password and address of website (all stored as `std::string`).

So, the only thing remaining is to decrypt the username and password strings.

I tried the following (`PK11Decrypt` ought to store the plaintext password in `plaintext`):

```
void Firefox_Importer::PK11Decrypt(string _cipheredBuffer, char **plaintext) {
  // declarations needed
  SECItem * request;
  SECItem * reply;
  unsigned int len = (unsigned int)_cipheredBuffer.length();
  const char* cipheredBuffer = (const char*)_cipheredBuffer.c_str();

  // generate request and reply SECItem; seems to work properly
  reply = SECITEM_AllocItem(NULL, NULL, 0);
  if (reply == NULL) cout << "Error allocating SECITEM." << endl;
  request = NSSBase64_DecodeBuffer(NULL, NULL, cipheredBuffer, len);
  if (request == NULL) cout << "Error decoding buffer." << endl;

  // the following is not working
  SECStatus tmp = PK11SDR_Decrypt(request, reply, NULL);
  if(tmp != SECSuccess) cout << "Something went wrong during decrypting" << endl;

  *plaintext = (char*)malloc(reply->len + 1);
  strncpy(*plaintext, (const char*)reply->data, reply->len);
  (*plaintext)[reply->len] = '\0';

  SECITEM_FreeItem(request, true);
  SECITEM_FreeItem(reply, true);
}
```

When `PK11Decrypt` is called, it prints `Something went wrong during decrypting`, indicating that the call to `PK11SDR_Decrypt` didn't work properly. It always returns `SECFailure` (which corresponds to -1).

Does anybody have some hints or know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the call to `PK11_Authenticate()` isn't optional, even if no master password is set (yes, NSS is pretty messed up). So you might need to do the following first:

```
PK11SlotInfo *slot = PK11_GetInternalKeySlot();
if (!slot) cout << "Error getting internal slot" << endl;

SECStatus tmp = PK11_Authenticate(slot, PR_TRUE, NULL);
if (tmp != SECSuccess) cout << "Authentication error" << endl;
```

Note that I pass `NULL` as context to `PK11_Authenticate()`, the context is only required if a password prompt should be displayed.

**Edit**: Never mind, I noticed that `PK11SDR_Decrypt()` will call both functions internally. Given that you get `SECFailure` as result, it is likely that `PK11_GetInternalKeySlot()` fails which would indicate that NSS isn't initialized properly.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Actually I did a stupid mistake, forgetting to call `NSS_Init`. Thank you.

Comment: What if master password is set? Can PK11SDR_Decrypt be used along with a known master password?

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati: I don't think that asking on a six years old question will get you very far. I'm not an NSS expert and cannot answer your question out of the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox is opensource software. You can find the most recent source [here](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/6.0.1/source/), it is up to you to find the part where they decrypt the passwords and copy it into your application. Good luck.

Comment: That's - in principle - a good point. However, I tried to build this thing upon http://mxr.mozilla.org/firefox/source/security/manager/ssl/src/nsSDR.cpp#179 and had no luck, thus I asked it here.

Comment: You probably need to initialize it first. Just read how they do it in the source it should not be hard.

Comment: "The part where they decrypt the passwords" would be [nsSecretDecoderRing](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/7d3d1c2c75f8/security/manager/ssl/src/nsSDR.cpp#l249) which at least at the first glance does the same as the code in the question.